# laravel api token - data not shows

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, api, vue.js

i tried to get my json data into my view using vuejs. i tried with api token. i generate a token with user register and saved it in a database row.

this is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $contact = Contact::all();

    $contactcount = count($contact);

    return json_encode([
      'contactcount' => $contactcount,
    ]);
}
```

and this is my vue js method

```
fletchDetails(){
    fetch('http://slfsnew.test/api/contact', {
          params: {
            api_token: this.api_token,
          }
        })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
    this.contact = res.contactcount;
    });
},
```

i tried to get my api token with a prop

```
data(){
return {
   contact: '',
   uri: 'http://slfsnew.test/api/contact',
   api_token: this.user.api_token,
   }
  }
```

and i define my vuejs component like this.

```
<contactform @if(auth()->check())
        :user="{{ auth()->user() }}"
    @endif></contactform>
```

this api token gets my data property and finally it shows me this error.

```
admin:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at 
position 0
```

how can i fix this. i want to get my count and shows it in a bootstrap card

```
<h3>{{ contact }} test</h3>
```

Comment: The one you post is client-side/js error. Find the server/network error of the API call (in Chrome you can see it in developer console > network tab) or in Laravel log. BTW, the Laravel way of returning JSON is `return response()->json(['contactcount' => $contactcount])` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses

Comment: @Yohanes Gultom i tested my response with insomnia api app and shows me result correctly

Comment: It does not really matter. To fix the issue, you need to know the error where it happens. Unless you do it, nobody would be able to help you

Comment: @Yohanes Gultom no error shows in network tab. only shows error in console i mentioned in my post

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` means that the server returns something else than JSON. The `<` indicates it is a markup language (XML/HTML). Now since you are using Laravel, most likely it is a HTML. Laravel only returns HTML unexpectedly when error occurs so there is no way there is no error. But if you are not sure how to use chrome network monitoring, try to log the response eg `.then(res => { console.log(res); return res.json(); })`

Comment: @Yohanes Gultom thank you for support i figure it out.